# Ошибка при импорте модуля finance из библиотеки matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, matplotlib

Не могу импортировать из библиотеки модуль.

`from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ochl`

Вызывает исключение:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с `matplotlib 2.0` [модуль `matplotlib.finance`](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html) был объявлен устаревшим (deprecated) и вынесен в отдельный модуль [mpl_finance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance).

> This module consists of code extracted from the deprecated
>   matplotlib.finance module along with a few examples of usage.
>
> *The code is provided as is and is basically un-maintained.*

[Пример использования](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/blob/master/examples/finance_demo.py):

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import MONDAY, DateFormatter, DayLocator, WeekdayLocator

from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc   #  pip install mpl_finance

date1 = "2004-2-1"
date2 = "2004-4-12"


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = pd.read_csv('data/yahoofinance-INTC-19950101-20040412.csv',
                     index_col=0,
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

# select desired range of dates
quotes = quotes[(quotes.index >= date1) & (quotes.index <= date2)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)

# plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
                         quotes['Open'], quotes['High'],
                         quotes['Low'], quotes['Close']),
                 width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]